# retry the calling function if theres an exception in the called function using python 3

Tags: python

I have a need to call the calling function if an exception is raised. I am aware of retrying the same function using a retry decorator but not sure how to retry the calling function

## module1.py

```
import module2    
def func1():
    module2.func2()
```

## module2.py

```
def func2():
    try:
       # do some computation    
    except Exception:
       func1()
```

how do I call func1 and stop if func2 throws the same exception again

Comment: Is there any reason why it is the responsibility of ``func2`` to call ``func1`` (and thus itself) again? Why doesn't ``func1`` retry ``func2`` on failure?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just need to catch the exception in `func1()`'s caller, don't you?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what exactly is the need to do this? What are you trying to achieve?